# Highlight Duplicate Row based on column A but exclude any rows that have a specific value in column B

Tags: excel, countif

I have an excel spreadsheet with Column A contianing duplicates and Column B that has an exclude factor.

[image]

I currently have conditional formatting on formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10, $A1)>1` that is highlighting any duplicate rows

[image]

I would like to add to this, that if Column B has an 'X', to exclude that row from the count so that it does not flag as a duplicate and my results would look like this instead

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10, $A1)>1,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10, $A1,$B$1:$B$10,"X")=0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm getting an error that there are too many arguments with this function

Comment: `=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10, $A1)>1,COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10, $A1,$B$1:$B$10,"X")=0)` sorry forgot the `S`